# Need to override style of ngx datatable in two different pages not impacting each other

Tags: datatable, overflow

```
".ngx-datatable datatable-header{
  overflow: visible !important;
}
.ngx-datatable {
  overflow: visible !important;
}"
```

I have two ngx datatables in two different pages,And I set customized filter in one datatable header by an filter icon, Problem is the dropdown of onclick of icon is cutting the dropdown,for that I googled and got to know that its an CSS issue and can be handled. So i written the following in my Angular SCSS file for one component related.

Using this working but impacting on other ngx datatables.

Help or suggest me any one on this.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't they both having separate CSS files? If that is the case, it shouldn't be affecting one another. If they are both having the same CSS file as the style sheet, provide an ID to each table and provide the same id in the CSS as well, so that the specified style gets added only to that Id.

Once you specify the ngx-datatable styles under the respective Id's, it should work.
Let me know if it worked.